# File not found Exception while accessing in Android 11 - Target SDK 30 - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

I am downloading audio and I want to play that downloaded audio within my app

From the below code, I am downloading the audio

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

```
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, finleName);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + sep + newFolder + sep);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, true);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
            Uri itemUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, contentValues);

            mediaFile = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + sep + newFolder + sep + finleName;
            Log.d("Path: ", mediaFile + "\nUri Path:" + uri.getPath() + "\nFile Path: " + itemUri.getPath());

            OutputStream output = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(itemUri);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, false);
            getContentResolver().update(itemUri, contentValues, null, null);
```

But when i try to access this downloaded file i am getting File Not Found Exception and i am unable to play audio

Here audio is getting downloaded successfully but still, it is not accessible.

Comment: Have you tried with "Manage External Storage" permission?

Comment: Yes but Playstore rejects my build with this permission enabled

Comment: You need to check file path by a different way .. you can get help from here :
https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java

Comment: `But when i try to access this downloaded file` Well show your code as when you can write to that uri you can certainly read from it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you make sure and confirm that the file is really available on the said path?
Try accessing using adb root. Locate it and verify/confirm if the audio file is present.

Please also add android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is totally ignored on Android 11 as you have to use scoped storage instead.